# TypeError: data.forEach is not a function. Error is like and I don't know why

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here I am trying to a scream and comments related to it.

```
exports.getScream = (req, res) => {
let screamData = {};
db.doc(`/screams/${req.params.screamId}`)
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Scream not found' });
    }
    screamData = doc.data();
    screamData.screamId = doc.id;
    return db
      .collection('comments')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .where('screamId', '==', req.params.screamId)
      .get();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    screamData.comments = [];
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      screamData.comments.push(doc.data());
    });
    return res.json(screamData);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
  });
};
```

But here I am getting error that data.forEach is not a function. Please help me why.

Comment: Can you log what you have in data after the `.then` clause?

Comment: Basically this code is to show the post and comments associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right, data is the resolved value of that database-promise above.

Try to type your "data" parameter as an array of your datatype like:

```
.then((data : dataType[]) => {
screamData.comments = [];
data.forEach((doc) => {
  screamData.comments.push(doc.data());
});
return res.json(screamData);
```

If this does not help, please ensure data is not null/undefined and provide the result of

`console.log(data)`

Comment: @AmbikaSharma above your line 'screamData.comments = [];', please insert a new line with console.log(data), run your program and post the result of this log here

Comment: It says the scream not found.

Comment: in that case @Frank van Puffelen is correct, the doc does not exist, so your data is the res-Object

Comment: The doc does exists because I am passing it's id. I don't know why this error still exists. Error lies in data.forEach. Please help me.

Comment: @AmbikaSharma console.log(doc) above 'if (!doc.exists)' and post the result please

Comment: It says doc does exist.

Comment: what does it look like?

Comment: DocumentSnapshot {
>    _fieldsProto: undefined,
>    _ref: DocumentReference {
>      _firestore: Firestore {
>        _settings: [Object],
>        _settingsFrozen: true,
>        _serializer: [Serializer],
>        _projectId: 'socialmedia-58643',
>        registeredListenersCount: 0,
>        _lastSuccessfulRequest: 1595512744031,
>        _backoffSettings: [Object],
>        _preferTransactions: false,
>        _clientPool: [ClientPool]
>      },

Comment: the problem is not the forEach. The data you get is not an array. If your first database call works as expected, the 2nd one is incorrect.

Comment: Im glad it worked, please mark an answer as most helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess is that this happens when the `scream` isn't found, because your first `then` in that case returns:

```
return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Scream not found' });
```

And this doesn't have a `forEach` method in there, so the second `then` fails.

I'd typically try to get to a single error handler, that exists in your final `catch` - so probably throw an exception in your first `then` that the `catch` then returns to the caller.

Comment: Which part of my answer wasn't clear? Which part **was** clear? What did you try in your code based on my answer? How did that change the problem?